# Bootstrap navbar input field too narrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a bootstrap based html that looks the way I want in Bootply, but in my page the query field looks narrower than it should. I just don't know what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Link</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">




        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="xxx.php">Sair</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>



        <form class="navbar-form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca" name="q"> 
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>


    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

Here is the desired result:
[image: desired result]

Here is the real result:
[image]

Comment: are you sure? because that code looks just fine. I pasted the dom in https://jsfiddle.net/9mrra8tc/embedded/result/  and it is looking like what you say is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing the default behavior. You can easily adjust this to accommodate your needs though. Assign the `form` a new class, add the appropriate width and you may want/need to adjust the top position.

See working Snippet at Full Page.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form-fw {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .input-group.input-group-fw {
    top: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Link</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="xxx.php">Sair</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form-fw" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-group-fw">
            <input type="text" class="form-control control-form" placeholder="Busca" name="q"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I changed the form class, and set the input-group "top: 8px" and it solved it! Thanks! If you want to edit your answer, I can vote it as the right answer.